# Iterating through XML file with XDocument returns element with no attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I'm iterating through all the child elements of this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
    <user name="SemiViral" access="2" />
</users>
```

with this code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Users.xml");

Console.WriteLine(doc.Descendants("users").Count());

foreach (XElement u in doc.Descendants("users")) {
    Console.WriteLine(u.Attributes().Count());
}
```

but the output from the `WriteLine` is `0`, and similarly empty if I try referencing the attributes directly. Counting the descendants returns `1` and when I added inner contents to the single child element, it was able to output those. So I know that it's the correct element, it's simply not accessing the attributes for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? This is quite obvious.

Comment: I haven't slept in some while and I'm very much a beginner at C#. I apologize if it's obvious, but I've mulled over this for an hour to no avail

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code to do what you are trying to do. You were not getting results because you were only looking for `users` elements (`doc.Descendants("users")`). The element that you are looking for is at the next level of the xml. If you debugged your code you would have spotted it.

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Users.xml");

            Console.WriteLine(doc.Descendants("users").Descendants().Count());

            foreach (XElement u in doc.Descendants("users").Descendants())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("value of the attribute is " + u.Attributes("access").First().Value);
            }
```

Comment: I'm `using System.Xml.Linq` and `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`, and the second `.Descendant()` is causing a conflict of ambiguousness.
`The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Descendants<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)' and 'System.Xml.Linq.Extensions.Descendants<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)'`

Comment: Why are you using Json.Linq? you only need System.Linq and System.Xml.Linq

Comment: Managing data from a GET request elsewhere in the application; that is received in JSON. This bit is for user storage, which I wanted to do in XML for simplicity. I didn't know this problem would occur.

Comment: One class is for one thing. That's what happen when you try to do too many things in the same class.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.